# Stop "filterablebeforefilter" from firing twice

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Is is possible to prevent this event from firing twice? 
If I type something in one of the two search fields (searchOne / SearchTwo), the event is fired twice...

```
$(function() {
    $("#searchOne, #searchTwo").on("filterablebeforefilter", function (e) 
   //....
```

HTML

```
<div id="divOne">
    <ul id="searchOne"
        data-role="listview"
        data-inset="true"
        data-filter="true"
        data-filter-placeholder="Search 1...">
    </ul>
</div>


<div id="divTwo">   
    <ul id="searchTwo"
        data-role="listview"
        data-inset="true"
        data-filter="true"
        data-filter-placeholder="Search 2..."></ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Are you using same _input_ for both? if yes, it will fire twice. If you dedicate an _input_ for each #searchOne/#searchTwo, it shouldn't fire twice.

Comment: Could you post some more information

Comment: @Omar, no two different ID for two different search-fields (should auto-complete)...

Comment: please post html markup.

Comment: it's firing once per listview http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/arTqd/

Comment: @Omar, I removed my code and tried your example. Works perfect! Must have been something else that was wrong... Thank you!

Comment: Glad to hear so. Another note, dont use `.ready()` or `$(function ()` in jQM to bind event. wrap code in `$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function ()`.

Comment: @Omar, Ok I change the $(function () to $(document).on("pagecreate", ... instead!

Answer (score 0):

not directly answering your question, but what you can do is,

you can bind the event to a class selector :

`$(".searchInput").on("filterablebeforefilter", function (e)`

then set the css class to both input fields

```
<input id="searchOne" class="searchInput" />
<input id="searchTwo" class="searchInput" />
```

Comment: This is doesn't solve the problem. Binding an event to one or multiple elements is the same. Event fires when an _element_ receives an event, in spite of how many elements are bound to an event.

Comment: That is true. Thanks. But I got it working now, see above comment from Omar.